# Как в kotlin в строку из ресурса добавить переменную?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

Нужно в присваиваемую строку: `bindingclass.tvDinner.setText(R.string.block2)`

добавить переменную: `var appleCount = bindingclass.etApple.text.toString().toInt()`

чтоб на выходе в `textview` было что то вроде этого:

> "я сегодня съел 15 яблок"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи используйте [`plurals`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#Plurals).

Добавьте ресурс `plurals` в `values-ru/string.xml`. Для русского языка важно, чтобы файл `string.xml` лежал в директории `values-ru` и чтобы были объявлены все три элемента: `one`, `few` и `many`:

```xml
<resources>
    ...
    <plurals name="block">
        <item quantity="one">Я сегодня съел %d яблоко</item>
        <item quantity="few">Я сегодня съел %d яблока</item>
        <item quantity="many">Я сегодня съел %d яблок</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

Теперь используйте метод [`getQuantityString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getQuantityString(int,%20int)), чтобы получить этот ресурс в коде:

```kotlin
val appleCount = 15
val text = resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.block, appleCount, appleCount)
```

Далее, установите полученный текст в TextView:

```kotlin
textView.setText(text)
```

Comment: Возможно ли в plurals добавить вторую переменную? Чтоб получился такой результат:
15 котов съели 18 яблок?

Comment: Нет, в таком случае разбейте строковый ресурс на два: "15 котов съели" и "18 яблок".

Answer (score 0):

```
<string name="test_string">Привет, это %s! Купишь яблоки?</string>  

val a = getString(R.string.test_string, "Wlad")
```